# Create a scrollable button list panel in Windows Form C# application

Tags: c#, winforms, button, scrollview

I'm trying to add a scrollable list of buttons inside a panel from C# scripting inside Visual Studio.

I can make the scrollbar and attach it to a panel and manually add buttons inside the panel from the UI but I want to code for the entire panel along with scrollbar and create buttons inside that newly created panel.

Can anyone help me with this?

In Unity I can use the OnGUI function and use the GUI class to add these features but I dont know how to do that in Winform application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you are trying to achieve somethings like this 
[image: Here] then just create a flowLayout pannel and Just add buttons to the flowlayout pannel and set the Autoscroll property of the flowlayout to true.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
{
  Button b = new Button();
  b.Text = "b" + i;
  flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
}
```

and set the autoscroll property for the flowlayoutpannel.

```
flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
```

Comment: yh thats exactly what im looking for. just one more questions: do i have to declare and initialize the flowLayoutPanel1 property outside of the for loop first? Cause it looks like you set the autoscroll property outside of the for loop.

Comment: thanks yu made it very simple and easy to understand. However I'm now thinking about the response function for each newly created button. From the script, how would I check which newly button is clicked and create a response function that would respond to that click only? Sorry for all this trouble

Comment: Then you have all your button object in the flowlayoutpannel and from there u can list to the button click event's

Comment: @MarkJackson has it worked for you if its worked then mark it as answer and do a upvote so that it will be helpful for other users

Comment: oh sorry it worked. I'm new to this statckoverflow system so I didn't know that lol